# What's wrong with my 9-patch PNG for Button

Tags: android

I created a 9-patch PNG but it won't work. In the Android SDK Tool everything looks ok. But when i add it to a Button then i only see a pink background. The text placement (padding from the patch) seems to be ok. What am i doing wrong?

```
     <Button 
    android:id="@+id/button_settings"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:text="Settings"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:background="@drawable/button_settings_idle"
/>
```

The 9-patch in the Android SDK Tool:

[image: The 9-patch in the Android SDK Tool]

A normal Button and the Button with the PNG:

[image: A normal Button and the Button with the PNG]

The PNG used in my project

[image: The PNG used in my project]

Comment: I'm sorry i really have no clue what you mean. The PNG is ok in the Android SDK 9-patch Tool, isn't it supposed to be right then?

Comment: Could you try to cut the 9-patch to the limit? so basically reduce the width to the very first pixel you want to stretch plus the padding? Also try to use the image inside a ImageView and see if it is successfully loaded there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paint your background image like a rainbow (diagonal gradient is the best), you will then see which part of image overlaps which and possibly why.

My guess: trim your picture horizontally (remove the middle part and make 9patch do it's job) then see what happens. If background picture is bigger than actual button, strange things happen - like overlapping "text area" over "fixed" image parts.

Answer (score 0):

maybe, you should draw between two points on top and left.

You can try to shift to the right point to left to imageWidth  for content??

Comment: that would cause the picture to resize.